# Jquery Steps stops datepicker working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-steps

I am using jquery steps for wizard. But inside if I use datepicker or qtip functionality not working.  I switched .js references still the issue the same.

Why datepicker event not working inside steps? console not throwing any error.

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, null, new {@class = "SPE-Formcontrol section_detail-font-14 calendar", @style = "display: inline", @readonly = "readonly", Name = "BirthDate", id = "BirthDate"})

 <script src="~/Scripts/join.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.steps.js"></script>
```

## join.js

```
 $("#BirthDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '-110:-17',
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage:"image",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    beforeShow: function () {
        $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index', 9999);
    },
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    maxDate: '-17Y'
});

$('.tip').qtip({
    style: {
        classes: 'myTipClass tipShadow qtip-rounded'
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you include the neccessary libraries for those plugins

Comment: yes I did. Steps showing and calendar icon showing. But click on datapicker not working.

Comment: The datepicker does require jQuery UI

Comment: if I comment ~/Scripts/jquery.steps.js datepicker works fine. so there is no issue with UI

Comment: @James123 Have any solution ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialize jquery steps first and then other plugin initialization

```
$(function () {
//intilize steps first
 $("#wizard").steps({
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    headerTag: "h4"
  });
//intilize other plugins later
 $("#BirthDate").datepicker();
});
```

Hopefully, this resolves your issue

Comment: You save my time. didnt realize this. i spent more than 2hours trying to fix this issue. thanks you...

Comment: Hello, same problem here;

this simple solution doesn't work for me

Comment: lastly you saved my time after near of hour stumbling upon web. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that datepicker puts triggers on elements and the class 'hasDatepicker' saying that this element has been initialized. Jquery steps moves elements around, triggers are lost.
But the datepicker elements still have the class after moving, thus won't be triggered again if you call datepicker once more. So if you want to reinitialize datepicker you should add this in jquery steps definition:

```
onInit: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
    // Remove hasDatepicker class from initialized elements and remove the button next to datepicker input
    $('.hasDatepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').siblings('.ui-datepicker-trigger').remove();

     // reinitialize datepicker, offcourse replace .datepickerfields with your specific datepicker identifier
     $('.datepickerfields').datepicker();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here
It works fine OUTSIDE the wizard, but once the input is set inside, the parent div of the datepicker does appear in the DOM, but it's empty...
No datepicker will appear

tried to declare the

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

BEFORE or AFTER the steps() function, nothing change.

I tried to use the onInit() feature of the steps() function, it still doesn't work

```
form.steps({
...
onInit : function (event, currentIndex) { $(".datepicker").datepicker(); },
...
});
```